# Error creating multiple durable queue's in qpid

Tags: python, amqp, qpid

When creating multiple durable queues i get the following error message:

`Failed: SessionException: (None, 'Queue stage-cart: create() failed: jexception 0x0400 fcntl::clean_file() threw JERR_FCNTL_OPENWR: Unable to open file for write. (open() failed: errno=24 (Too many open files)) (MessageStoreImpl.cpp:538)')`

I know this issue is related to the `qpid.file_count` because I don't receive this message for every durable queue and if I convert enough queues to non-durable I wont see the message at all. How do I allocate enough space on qpid and/or my machine to prevent this from happening?